# SQL Server Replication issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, database-replication, data-synchronization

I'm trying to set database snapshot replication using c# with SQL Server 2008 R2. when I'm connecting to the server everything goes as it should... but after the following lines of the code:

```
distributor = new ReplicationServer(conn);
distributor.InstallDistributor((string)null, distributionDb);
```

the following error occurs:

> *This edition of SQL Server cannot act as a Publisher or Distributor for replication. Changed database context to 'master'*

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a full copy of SQL (Develper, Enterprise...) to support publications.

Comment: Are you using express? That version can only act as a subscriber.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the express version. I'll try out the enterprise version - this should do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Replication Considerations (SQL Server Express)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686.aspx), SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Publisher or Distributor, only as a Subscriber.  You will need a Standard Edition or higher instance to configure distribution and setup a publication.  The Express Edition instance can then serve as a Subscriber.

> SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Publisher or Distributor.